# magento checkout struck at billing information for some customers

Tags: magento

we are facing a strangest problem ever in live site.

for **some** registered customers [email id ], when they enter Billing address and click on "continue" button,

**its not moving to the next step. Instead of this ,its coming back to the previous step.**

we are using https for checkout. This is ajax response :
[image]

console :[image]

Comment: Have you check the magento logs and the console in browser ?

Comment: please check updated question, i added console image

Comment: is it happening for particular  customers or for random customers , and it will be good if you can share a magento log also

Comment: randiom customers, i will share log in few minutes.....

Comment: system.log = http://pastebin.com/dmJZZn4B

Comment: exception.log : http://pastebin.com/KSDQExPX

Comment: can you just clear all  log and try again and paste only the new log you getting in case of error

Comment: strange , but  i did the same and posted here....

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101893/discussion-between-rohit-goel-and-baby-in-coding).

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be remove Shipping Address step on checkout page.

But on  checkout billing step ,you have set **`billing[use_for_shipping]`** value as **0**.For this 0 value you need to got at shipping address step but it is not exit;

So You need to  set  **`billing[use_for_shipping]`** value as **1** (Means Ship to same address) to directly goto at Shipping method step Ship to this address